# JBossMQ - Clustered Queues/NameNotFoundException: QueueConnectionFactory error

Tags: cluster, jboss

I am trying to get an application working on a JBoss Cluster.  It uses Queues internally, and the developer claims that it should work correctly in a clustered environment.  I have jbossmq setup as a ha-singleton on the cluster.  The application works correctly on whichever node currently is running the queue, but fails on the other nodes with a: "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: QueueConnectionFactory not bound"  error.  I can look at JNDIview from the jmx-console and see that indeed the QueueConnectionFactory class only appears on the primary node in the Global context.  Is there a way to see the Cluster's JNDI listing instead of each server?

The steps I took from a default Jboss 4.2.3.GA installation were to use the "all" configuration. Then removed /server/all/deploy/hsqldb-ds.xml and /deploy-hasingleton/jms/hsqldb-jdbc2-service.xml, copying the example/jms/mysq-jdbc2-service.xml file into its place (editing that file to use DefaultDS instead of MySqlDS).  Finally I created a mysql-ds.xml file in the deploy directory pointing "DefaultDS" at an empty database.  I created a -services.xml file in the deploy directory with the queue definition. like the one below:

```
<server>
        <mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue"
                name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=myfirstqueue">
                <depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">
                        jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager
                </depends>
        </mbean>
</server>
```

All of the other cluster features of working, the servers list each other in the view, and sessions are replicating back and forth.  The JBoss documentation is somewhat light in this area, is there another setting I might have missed?  Or is this likely to be a code issue (is there different code to do a JNDI lookup in a clusted environment?)

Thanks

Comment: From the code the problem seems to be this resource pulled in by the failing module.  The developer believes jboss should correctly fetch this resource from the cluster context, but I can't find anything that confirms that.  @Resource(name="QueueConnectionFactory",mappedName="QueueConnectionFactory")

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the code.  The @resource syntax is apparently not cluster compliant.  The developer tried another method and it works correctly.